# How to use Triangle.Net in a Unity project?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, triangle.net

I'm working on a project in Unity and found the Triangle.Net package (http://triangle.codeplex.com/) to be useful for helping me generate triangulations. However, I have no idea what to do with the files once I download them. I've been searching around for the longest time about how to even get started with .net libraries, but have not found a single source. Could anyone guide me in the right direction?

I'm using MonoDevelop 4.0.1 if that is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is apparently no binaries available, you will have to build the project yourself.

- Download and unzip the Triangle.NET project source
- Open the solution in your IDE
- Build the solution
- In your project where you want to use Triangle.NET, right click the *References* node, and select "Add reference"; then browse to the location of the Triangle.NET binaries (typically in the bin\Debug or bin\Release subdirectory)